# How to use root permission while copying, moving and extracting files

Tags: command-line, permissions, lamp, xampp

I am new user in ubuntu and i am a web developer especially wordpress developer. So I have installed xampp and after downloading wordpress zip file I moved it to /opt/lampp/htdocs/ But whenever I am trying to extract the zip file it shows me an error like "there was an error while extracting wordpress.zip". It also happen when i try to copy or move any file from my desktop or home to htdocs or other system folders.

I can copy,move files using terminal with sudo. But is there any other solution that I can extract files, copy or move using GUI.

Maybe I was not good enough to explain. Please forgive my mistakes and tell me how can I fix those.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu: Have a look at nautilus-admin. It will let you open, copy, edit and delete files and folders as admin.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to run nautilus as root I use `sudo -H nautilus` and I get the file browser with root privileges.

Don't use sudo without the -H in this case though.